# Calling method on singleton before initialization finished

Tags: c++, singleton

When converting an old Visual Studio 2003 project to 2015, I ran into an issue where the application freezes right after start. I can't seem to get much information out of the debugger because the application is not really crashing.

When I pause the debugger, it always points to the same line of code, the static variable in a singleton GetInstance method. This makes it look like the app is waiting for it to be initialized. The constructor of this object is calling a method that uses this same GetInstance method, so the instance is being used before the constructor ends.

This is how the code works:

```
//A.cpp
A::A()
{
    B::GetInstance()->DoSomething();
}

A* A::GetInstance()
{
    static A instance; // The debugger always points out that this line is next to be executed after pausing the application
    return &instance;
}

//B.cpp
void B::DoSomething()
{
    A::GetInstance()->DoSomethingElse();
}
```

I understand that this code can be improved and there are ways to work around it, but I'm wondering why this code worked fine in Visual Studio 2003 and breaks in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a simple deadlock on the static intialization "mutex".

Comment: Have you initialized the static variable outside the class? Also why not `static A* instance`. Also your `GetInstance` is not `static`

Comment: @macroland Using `static A instance;` is very good idea. C++11 guarantees that function local static variables initialisation is thread-safe.

Comment: @Lehu: That's typically done by using a lock, or pthread_once or similar, and if the constructor calls GetInstance() directly or indirectly, you get a deadlock. That's exactly what happens with the code above.

Comment: @Lehu Answer looked mostly right. If not THE BUG, certainly a bug. Just needed a better explanation of the loop.

Comment: @gnasher729 I agree. It just doesn't mean that using `static A instance;` should be avoided. Calls to `GetInstance()` in constructor should be avoided :) . As a matter of fact, according to what Bjarne, Herb and some other smart people say: singletons should be avoided :) .

Comment: @user4581301 Well... I'm not a master of multithreading and it seems that rather than infinite recursion I mentioned we have deadlock here (as Kerrek SB and gnasher729 said) so I step down and let other people have their moment of glory ;) .

Comment: @Lehu You're both right, sort of. I'll write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lehu was mostly right in their deleted answer. It's a circular reference that would go recursive if not blocked by a mutex. Here's what happens:

1. `B::DoSomething()` called
2. `B::DoSomething()` invokes `A::GetInstance()`
3. `A::GetInstance()` calls constructor `A::A()` to construct `static A instance`. This locks a critical section around the creation of `instance` to make sure the job can be finished without interruptions.
4. `A::A()` invokes `B::DoSomething();` See the circle forming?
5. `B::DoSomething()` invokes `A::GetInstance()`
6. `A::GetInstance()` attempts to access `instance`, but `instance` has not yet finished constructing, so execution halts until it can.

Unfortunately step 3 can't complete until step 6 completes This is a classic deadlock: 3 is waiting for 6 to complete and 6 is waiting for 3 to complete. [To Quote Pvt. Hudson, "Game over, man! Game over!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdqyG3CcoLM)

Edit: Thinking this over, mutex isn't quite the right term. A [Crtitcal Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) around acquiring the static variable `instance` is more appropriate.

My cut of an MCVE to demonstrate:

```
struct A
{
    A();
    static A* GetInstance()
    {
        static A instance; 
        return &instance;
    }
    void DoSomethingElse()
    {

    }
};
struct B
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        A::GetInstance()->DoSomethingElse();
    }
    static B* GetInstance()
    {
        static B instance; 
        return &instance;
    }
};

A::A()
{
    B::GetInstance()->DoSomething();
}


int main()
{
    B::GetInstance()->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there any particular reason why this could have worked in Visual Studio 2003? I haven't changed these classes during the upgrade and it worked fine before.

Comment: @ExplodingSoap The deadlock stems from protection of a static variable in a multi-threaded environment. C++ didn't really acknowledge the existence of threads until the C++11 standard, so odds are good that this case was not automatically handled before MSVC started picking up pieces of C++11 back in MSVC 2010 and probably not until later.

Comment: That said, my hack MCVE shouldn't work under older versions of visual studio because it'll get locked in a recursive trap. Your actual implementation may differ.

Comment: @ExplodingSoap Tried this out on MSVC 2010. Looks like the code walks deep into Undefined Behaviour (`instance` was used before initialization completed) and then manages to get back out looking not too bad off. In other words, you got unlucky and broken code looked like it worked.